# the record bigger than max_allowed_packet in migration

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migration

I have got a problem while making migration for sql server database to mysql via mysql workbench tells me the record is bigger than the (max_allowed_packet) .. I have increased the max_allowed_packet in my.ini file for phpmyadmin and workbench to (1G) and by writing the query :
set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000

but I still have the same problem while migrating .. I have tried to restart xampp
but nothing happened .

please can you help me .